# Numpy Lambda Function Not Working as Expected

Tags: python, numpy

market['AAPL'] is a dataframe with Apple's daily stock return

I noticed that:

```
market['AAPL'].apply(lambda x: np.exp(x))

market['AAPL'].apply(lambda x: np.cumprod(np.exp(x)))
```

Both give the same results
Why is the np.cumprod not working?

Comment: What is the type of x (each value in `market['AAPL']`)? Is it a scalar or an array, and if an array, are you sure there is more than 1 element?

Comment: please post a sample input/output so we can help better. Thank you

Comment: What do you expect `cumprod` to do?

Comment: Since apply works row-wise, and the elements of the AAPL column are probably single numbers, not arrays, np.cumprod doesn't add anything, as it will work on a single numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean to apply the cumulative product across the AAPL column. Your current attempt doesn't work, because `.apply` works per row. As a result, `np.cumprod` is called each time for a single number, not for an array of numbers.

Instead, try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

aapl = {"AAPL": np.linspace(1, 2, 10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(appl)
# Calculate exp for the column, then calculate 
# the cumulative product over the column
df['cum-AAPL'] = np.exp(df['AAPL']).cumprod())
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `x` is a number, it's `np.exp` is a number, and a product of one number is itself.